# Dashboard of Crashlytics redirect to get-start page everytime

Tags: ios, objective-c, crashlytics

I swear I've done everything they told.

1. Run your app from Xcode to install it on the simulator or your device
2. Press the Stop button in Xcode to quit it
3. Launch your app from the home screen to run it without the debugger
4. Press the “Crash” button to trigger the crash
5. Run the app again from Xcode so it can deliver the recorded crash to Crashlytics.

I do some settings in my `'AppDelegate.m'`

```
    [Crashlytics sharedInstance].debugMode = YES;
    [Fabric with:@[[Crashlytics class]]];
    [[Crashlytics sharedInstance] setUserName:@"iOS white"];
    [[Crashlytics sharedInstance] setUserIdentifier:@""];
    [[Crashlytics sharedInstance] setUserEmail:@"dev@oecore.com"];
```

I'm sure that Debug Information Format is “DWARF with dSYM File” for both Debug and Release.

But when I force crash on my app, and relaunch it from home screen.No matter how long I wait, dashboard page still redirect to get-start page.
Appreciate for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your app was in a weird state on our backend. I manually enabled it so it should appear now on your dashboard and start collecting crashes.

Comment: Awesome. That's great to hear!